# Zapi API: How to login to Zephyr using Zapi API in order to fetch detail or update any Test case

Tags: java, jira-zephyr

I am new to Zapi(Zephyr API). I am trying to evaluate Zapi API for automated test case result updation. While trying to fetch detail about test case using it I am getting "Please log in" message on console.
I am trying to use Zapi Rest API from below link:
http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/.

Below is the code I am using to fetch details of a particular test case:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Response response = client.target("https://SERVER_NAME").path("/jira/browse/DEV-3121").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get();
        System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
        System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
        System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));
```

And I am getting below message on console:

```
<fieldset class="hidden parameters">
    <input type="hidden" title="loggedInUser" value="">
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxTimeout" value="The call to the JIRA server did not complete within the timeout period.  We are unsure of the result of this operation.">
    <input type="hidden" title="JiraVersion" value="6.2.7" />
    <input type="hidden" title="ajaxUnauthorised" value="You are not authorized to perform this operation.  Please log in.">
<fieldset/>
```

Please let me know, what I am missing here or else is there any other way I can get access to fetch details for a test case or update any test case in Jira-Zephyr.

Thanks.

Comment: you forgot the message.

Comment: @duffy356 I am getting a HTML response in console, and I have pasted the Message for Login above. If needed I can paste the whole HTML reponse,

Answer (score 0):

You need to send request with base64 encoded authorization headers like this:

## Authorization header uses base64 encoded username and password string

headers = {"Authorization": " Basic " + b64encode(username + ":" + password), "Content-Type": "application/json"}